# Should I run all saga when launch app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I've just started to learn and use redux-saga, at first I thought it worked this way: first you make action which is connected to saga, then saga detects action,calls api which returns data and saga returns this data to reducer. I built 2 testing saga files and one root saga (I wanted to make rootSaga, like combineReducer), so this is my rootSaga :

```
import * as SpreadsheetSagas         from "../pages/spreadsheet/containers/spreadsheet/spreadsheet.saga";
import * as SpreadsheetFilterSagas   from "../pages/spreadsheet/containers/spreadsheet_filter/spreadsheet_filter.saga";

export default function* rootSaga() {
  yield all([
    ...Object.values(SpreadsheetSagas),
    ...Object.values(SpreadsheetFilterSagas)
  ].map(fork))
}
```

and this is one of my saga function:

```
export function* getData() {
   const response = yield call(ApiService.get);
   const payload = response ? response.data : {};
   //send returned object back to reducer as payload:
   yield put({ type: 'GET_MOCK_DATA', payload});
}
```

and my store folder looks like:

```
const middleWare = [];

// Setup Redux-Saga.
const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
middleWare.push(sagaMiddleware);

const store = createStore(rootReducer, {}, 
compose(applyMiddleware(...middleWare)));

// Initiate the root saga.
sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
```

So, when I run my app, it calls every saga functions - and this is correct way to implement sagas :? or I should have several rootSaga files which will be depend on current page, and then when I open page, run appropriate rootSaga? I hope I explained everything correctly :/ please give me any suggestions. thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think generally you just have one tree of sagas that relate to your entire app, not multiple root sagas for different pages/routes. You just attach the rootSaga once, as middleware.

So yes, when your app starts the entire tree of sagas starts and beings watching actions. Sagas interact globally with your store, so it makes sense for them to start globally with your app.

Only start the sagas that watch for actions (using `take`, `takeEvery` etc). Other sagas that make side effects, or call apis, shouldn't be invoked when your app starts.

Creating a tree of sagas similar to reducers and `combineReducer` is the right way to go too.

Comment: yes I did that, but saga files must call api right? and if that so, is this correct to call so many requests which actually you don't need on first page, why should I do that :? probably I don't understand something :? :/

Comment: You need to split up such sagas - one saga that watches for the action type, and then another saga that actually performs the api request. It's only the watcher that you should run from your rootSaga. Check the docs and example code here: https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/master/docs/basics/DeclarativeEffects.md

Comment: I did as it was in example code, in one function I wrote 'yield takeEvery('PRODUCTS_REQUESTED', helloSaga2)' and 'helloSaga2' - in this function - 'const products = yield call(ApiService.get);' , but still, when I run my app it does api request. Should I run only those  saga functions which are not call any request :?

Comment: Yep, only start the sagas that watch for actions (using `take`, `takeEvery` etc). Other sagas that make side effects, or call apis, shouldn't be started when your app starts.